# Selenium Can't Locate Field Inside of Frame

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate an object inside of a frame, but Selenium keeps returning that it timed out trying to locate the element.

Here is the relevant code information:

The frame ID is `tasks-splash-content`.  I am switching to it with this method call `SeleniumCommands.myDriver.switchTo().frame("tasks-splash-content");`

The field I am trying to locate and send keys to has an id of `txt_dateofbirth` and xpath of `html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]/input[1]`.  So far, both selection methods have not worked for me.

Here is the function body of my method that finds an element by xpath `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath)));`

So, sequentially, I am switching to the frame, waiting until the field is visible, and then trying to send it some values.  Does anyone know what might be causing this to not work for me?

Frame HTML:

```
<div id="tasks-splash-window" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 638px; padding: 0px;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0">
<iframe id="tasks-splash-content" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://qa3.jobappdemo.com/apply/c_tca/l_en/applied/OpenForms.cfm?dr=i9&hp=1204988&fid=401">
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe width="890" height="635" frameborder="0" src="https://qa3.jobappdemo.com/jobapp/get_appl_i9.cfm?hired_profile_id=1204988&hired_id=1204930&i9_id=902486&lang=en&new=1&rnd=327">
</body>
</html>
</iframe>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *nested `iframe`* you need to search in:

```
SeleniumCommands.myDriver.switchTo().frame("tasks-splash-content");
SeleniumCommands.myDriver.switchTo().frame(0);  // switch to the very first iframe
```

Also, note that the XPath expression you've presented is not quite reliable, try to rely on ids, data-oriented classes and attributes, or meaningful containers or neighbors.

Comment: Hi Alexce, thanks for your assistance.  That did work.  Do I have to add `SeleniumCommands.myDriver.switchTo().frame("tasks-splash-content");` and then `SeleniumCommands.myDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();` to get back to the main content then?

Comment: @lmcphers I think `SeleniumCommands.myDriver.switchTo().defaultContent();` would bring you back to the initial default content (with no active iframe context). Glad to help!

Comment: Is there a way to go back a frame from inside `frame(0)`?  I tried to go back up a frame using `SeleniumCommands.myDriver.switchTo().frame("tasks-splash-content")` to try to close the frame, but it can't locate that frame from `frame(0)`

Comment: @lmcphers I think you would have to go to the default content and switch to the `tasks-splash-content` again..

Comment: Boo, okay, thank you!  Forgive my minor sidetracking. :)